# propensity to pay in healthcare Datasets

Tags: dataset

I am searching for datasets or data sources (free or paid) to do a propensity to pay for healthcare industry.
I found many solutions that offer complete solutions but whats interesting to me that they always include 3rd party data sources. I wanted to know where I can find such data, and where also can I ask.

Comment: Please Post the question in Open Data Stack Exchange. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/